# Single Product URL Path

Tags: url

I'm struggling with the single product URL path.

If I go to `horloges-mannen.nl/herenhorloges/casio.html` (just an example), I can choose between the recommended and just watches brand itself. When I click on one from the **recommended list**, it gives this URL: `horloges-mannen.nl/a158w`.

But when I click by the other watches, it gives this URL: `horloges-mannen.nl/herenhorloges/casio/a158w`

How can I get them all the same way, like the `/category/subcategory/product` URL (2nd from those 2 links)?

Comment: Why do you want that? If it's for SEO, there's a better solution which is to enable the "Canonical URL" in Magento's configuration.

Comment: It's not for SEO, it's just to let it look nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are huge discussion what is better from a SEO perspective, having the category in the URL or not.

Magento creates a rewrite for each category the product is in. Turning on the `Canonical URL` as @Dan suggested, avoids penalties for duplicate content.

The only "out of the box" way to have only one URL is, to turn category in URL off. (this is what I heard at the moment the recommended way, but I'm no SEO expert)

To have only one URL per product, you have to remove the category from the URL:

```
System > Config > Catalog > Catalog 
> Search Engine Optimization > Use Categories Path for Product URLs: no
```

Answer on the comment

> What I want, is the full categoriers path for every product, also if I click on recomended, you're telling me the complete opposite right now ;)

Yes, I did. To fix this I think you should still turn it off and change the indexer which writes the url rewrite, to use one (or the only) category of a product, so when a product url is requested from the url_rewrite, you get the one with the whole categories in it.

Comment: I don't want it for SEO especially, the owner of the site just want it to look nicer when you choose a product, so you don't get 2 different links.

Comment: just turn it of ;) :D

Comment: What do you mean by turn it off?

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: What I want, is the full categoriers path for every product, also if I click on recomended, you're telling me the complete opposite right now ;)

Comment: Updated again..